# Error, Must specify valid information for parsing in the string, when using EF Core Value Conversion

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Based on the EF Core docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions), I'm trying to use EF Core's new Value Conversion on an enumeration. I want to save the enumeration as a string in the SQL Database table.

Here's the entity and enumeration.

```
public enum InputSetType
{
    TypeA, TypeB
}

public class MonthlyInputSet
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public InputSetType Type { get; set; }
}
```

Here is where I configure the MonthlyInputSet Entity:

```
public class MonthlyInputSetConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<MonthlyInputSet>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MonthlyInputSet> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(mis => mis.Type).HasConversion(v => v.ToString(), v => (InputSetType)Enum.Parse(typeof(InputSetType), v));
    }
}
```

So, I try to run a basic query to get this data and it fails. The query is:

```
var saved = await _context.MonthlyInputSets.Include(mis => mis.InsertedBy)
                                                     .Include(mis => mis.UpdatedBy)
                                                     .Include(mis => mis.MonthlyInputs)
                                                         .ThenInclude(mi => mi.EmissionsUnit)
                                                     .FirstOrDefaultAsync(mis => mis.Id == id);
```

But, an error is thrown on the first line of this query that says, "ArgumentException: Must specify valid information for parsing in the string." So my guess is that I have not properly configured the conversion of the string in the table to the enum in C#.

Full raw stack trace:

[image]

I verified that the correct string value is being returned from the database. It is not null and it is not a blank string. The string value returned matches a member of the enum perfectly.

```
 public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MonthlyInputSet> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(mis => mis.Type).HasConversion(
            convertToProviderExpression: v => v.ToString(), 
            convertFromProviderExpression: v => Troubleshooting(v)
        );
    }

    private InputSetType Troubleshooting(string v)
    {
        return (InputSetType)Enum.Parse(typeof(InputSetType), v);
    }
```

these two images show that the text in every row in the database type column is identical to the 2nd member of the enum that is mapped to this field.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Post the actual error, don't describe it. Post the full exception text returned by `Exception.ToString()`. This includes the call stack that shows *which* method calls resulted in that error. Most likely it's because `Enum.Parse(typeof(InputSetType), v))` doesn't check what `v` contains and could fail on a `Null` or an invalid value.

Comment: Can `InputSetType` be null? In that case the `Type` should be nullable and the conversion should return `null` if the database value is itself `null`

Comment: I verified there are no nulls in the Type column. This is a greenfield development and so there are only 12 rows in the column. I set them all to a string that is identical to one of the names in the enum. In this case I have left this as a not null field. I will always provide the type for all rows.

Comment: Which are? What is the enum, what are the names? Did you try debugging? What happens when that error is thrown? What's the value of `v` ? Have you trying to use `Enum.Parse(typeof(InputSetType), v)` with that value directly? PS: use `Enum.TryParse` instead of `Enum.Parse` and log the invalid value before throwing

Comment: And *please* post the exception as a string in the question. Images are hard to read, can't be copied, googled, or compiled

Comment: Enum is above in the question. When I step into the entity query it crashes out immediately with the above exception. Does it matter that I am using the IEntityTypeConfiguration Configure versus using the OnModelBuilding event to configure the value conversion?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the conversion method. What is the value of `v` there? If you can't put a breakpoint due to the oneliners, extract them to separate methods. You can't fix any parsing error when you don't even know what the string that fails is

Comment: Is `v` *empty* perhaps? `Empty` isn't null

Comment: Great suggestion. I changed the convertFromProviderExpression to a private function and put a break point in it and confirmed that the correct string value is in fact coming from the database. v is not empty. Each row has a correct value that maps to one of the items in the enum. I copied and pasted the text in the Type column in the table to be certain that I was not simply mis-typing the enum member. They are identical.

Comment: you still haven't posted anything in the question itself. What did `v` contain when the exception occured? Post something that can actually reproduce the problem

Comment: It contained the string "PerformanceReport" which is exactly what I expect/want it to contain. I want that to map to my enumeration. I added images to show both. Based on the docs I do seem to be using this correctly. There must be a bug with this feature.

Comment: You didn't post any enum that accepts `PerformanceReport` as a value. Besides, that functionality is there since 2002. It's not broken until you can actually prove otherwise, with an actual reproducible example that contains **only** the enum, the string value and the `Enum.Parse` call. If what you claim is true, that simple example will throw. `Extreme claims require extreme evidence` as they say and I can post a one-liner that shows there's no error

Comment: No repro. This runs properly:  `public enum InputSetType{CoalAnalysis,PerformanceReport}

void Main(){  Enum.Parse(typeof(InputSetType),"PerformanceReport");}` while `Enum.Parse(typeof(InputSetType),"performanceReport");` throws `Requested value 'performanceReport' was not found.`

Comment: The problem is with EF Core, not with Enum.Parse. I agree with you that Enum.Parse works great, of course. EF Core has a bug here, I am telling you. Either that or the docs are missing something.

Comment: The exception you posted proves the error is thrown by `Enum.Parse`. That screenshot proves the error was raised by `Enum.TryParseEnum` which in turn was called by `Enum.ParseEnum`. You've already proven that the error isn't raised by EF. You can claim that the value was changed somehow, but that can easily be checked if you just log the value that causes the problem. Use `TryParseEnum` yourself and *log* the failing value before throwing an exception

Comment: LOL I just figured it out. The issue had nothing to do with MonthlyInputSet and it was the MonthlyInput collection that is related to MonthlyInputSet. If you follow it with the debugger, it completely misdirects you as to where the failure actually lies.

Comment: That's why you actually have to log errors

Comment: Fair, but perhaps Microsoft could make a debugger that actually works properly? That would also help out a lot!

Answer (score 3):

The only way I can reproduce this error is for `v` to be an **empty string**, ie `""`. Not a null.

This :

```
Enum.Parse(typeof(InputSetType),"xx")
```

Throws `Requested value 'xx' was not found.`.

While this:

```
 Enum.Parse(typeof(InputSetType),"")
```

Throws :

```
Must specify valid information for parsing in the string. (Parameter 'value')
```

It seems some rows contain **an empty string** instead of `null`.

You'll have to decide what to do with those values - are they bad data? Or should the application handle them and replace them with some default value?

If you decide to use a default value you could use `S`tring.IsEmpty`or`String.IsNullOrWhitespace` to handle them, eg:

```
v=> String.NullOrWhitespace(v)?InputSetType.Unknown:Enum.Parse(typeof(InputSetType),v)
```

Comment: The documentation located here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions) has a note that says, "A null value will never be passed to a value converter. This makes the implementation of conversions easier and allows them to be shared amongst nullable and non-nullable properties)". And that's exactly how my code is structured and I have no nulls in the field. In fact, EF made the column as NOT NULL, so I do not believe null values are causing the error.

Comment: @tnk479 an empty string isn't the same as `null`. The error you posted can only be raised if an empty string is used. That documentation says nothing about empty strings, just nulls.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this exception is caused by invalid data in the database - data, that is not present in the enum, null, empty string or so on. This error is common in `Enum.Parse()` so I think it is related to this method.

Comment: I verified the string in the column is identical to one of the names within the enum. That should eliminate this possibility, right? I am asking EF Core to translate the enum to a varchar(max) field in the database and the reverse when querying.